# Animations are (occasionally) laggy

Tags: java, android, animation

I have 4 `TextViews`. They all start off invisible and I am animating them onto the screen (sliding in from the bottom). I start a thread to animate each one in, starting 200 milliseconds after each other. The problem is: the FIRST time I animate the TextViews after starting the activity, they lag. But if I animate them again afterwards, they do not. And occasionally they will lag randomly, but this isn't very frequent. I'm just wondering if there is a way to prevent this. I have only tested on one phone so it might be that, but it's weird it only happens on the first animation after starting the activity.

```
    animatingGroup = 0;
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (animate) {

                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        Animation slideInAnim = AnimationUtils
                                .loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),
                                        R.anim.slide_in_from_bottom);
                        switch (animatingGroup) {
                        case 1:
                            tv1.startAnimation(slideInAnim);
                            tv1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            tv2.startAnimation(slideInAnim);
                            tv2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            tv3.startAnimation(slideInAnim);
                            tv3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            tv4.startAnimation(slideInAnim);
                            tv4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            animate = false;
                            break;
                        }
                        animatingGroup++;
                    }
                });
            }

        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
```

and here is the animation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
       android:duration="800"
       android:toYDelta="0%"
       android:fromYDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

Comment: Use a handler.postdelayed() instead of thread.sleep and where is this code at? also remove your thread and use runnable instead..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont create your slideInAnim Insider the handler,it will eat up resources like hell, try creating it once ... in onCreate() perhaps

EDIT :
This is in my opinion a clean and simple way to do what you want to achieve :

Put your Textviews in an Array :

```
TextView[] textViews = new TextView[]{tv1,tv2,tv3,tv4};
```

Make a for loop that handles the animations startOffset :

```
int startOffset = 200;

for(int i=0; i < textViews.length(); i++){
    animSlideIn.setStartOffset(startOffset);
    textViews[i].setVisibility(View.Visible);
    textViews[i].startAnimation(animSlideIn);
    startOffset = startOffset + 200;
}
```

That way you can cut the new Thread and Handler Runnable stuff, and save a lot of code.

Comment: I also think the while loop is ugly and might be responsible for the lag, you might want to overthink the whole design. Try getting rid of the while loop and the New Thread and use an AnimationListener to start ,stop and clear animations instead

Comment: Well, the purpose of the while loop is to start each animation 200 milliseconds after each other. Removing it would cause them to animate at the same time, so I need something to keep this functionality

Comment: You can for example set a startOffset of 200 ms in your animation. That way it will wait 200ms and then start

Comment: I deleted some non helping comments and updated my answer, let me know if its working or if you need more help.

Comment: This helped a lot. I don't see the lag now (not yet, at least). However, I still have to create a new Animation for each iteration of the loop. If I assign the animation before the loop and reuse it for each iteration, the animation is applied to ALL of the TextViews at one time. But my main problem is solved, thanks